# Spring Boot LDAP Auth NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I'm trying to set up ldap authentication using spring boot.  I've done this on another project a while back setting up the authorization through the tomcat context file. So I already have a working setup to reference, just not in spring boot format.

In my SecurityConfiguration I add

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com")
                .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldaps://ldap.company.com:424")
                    .managerDn("CN=managerUser,OU=services,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com")
                    .managerPassword("password");
    }
```

Now when the app starts, I go to a secure resource, enter basic auth credentials, I get the print out in the console window that looks like everything is going fine.  It finds the user. Then it finishes with this error.

```
2018-03-06 17:40:22.632 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'user'
2018-03-06 17:40:22.632 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.Lda
pAuthenticationProvider
2018-03-06 17:40:22.632 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: user
2018-03-06 17:40:22.632 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user 'user', with user search [ searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={0})', searchBase: 'DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2018-03-06 17:40:22.671 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com', filter = '(sAMAccountName={0})'
2018-03-06 17:40:22.690 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: CN=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com
2018-03-06 17:40:22.694 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as cn=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com
2018-03-06 17:40:22.695 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : Removing pooling flag for user cn=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com
2018-03-06 17:40:22.717 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Retrieving attributes...
2018-03-06 17:40:22.719 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator : Getting authorities for user cn=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com
2018-03-06 17:40:22.720 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator : Searching for roles for user 'user', DN = 'cn=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com', with filter (uniqueMember={0}) in search base ''
2018-03-06 17:40:22.721 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Using filter: (uniqueMember=cn=user\5c, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com)
2018-03-06 17:40:22.760 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-03-06 17:40:22.762 DEBUG 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-03-06 17:40:22.764 ERROR 7308 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        ''
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        ''
 ]; remaining name ''
```

I'm pretty stumped what its expecting from me. All the other questions I viewed with this error seemed like their queries were failing.  But this one is clearly succeeding in finding the user before the error is generated.

Edit: 
I had them create me a test user with no comma in the name since that was a focus point for people.  That doesn't seem to resolve the error.

```
2018-03-07 13:59:52.569 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: CN=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com
2018-03-07 13:59:52.571 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as cn=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com
2018-03-07 13:59:52.572 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : Removing pooling flag for user cn=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com
2018-03-07 13:59:52.588 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Retrieving attributes...
2018-03-07 13:59:52.591 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator : Getting authorities for user cn=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com
2018-03-07 13:59:52.591 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator : Searching for roles for user 'TESTER1', DN = 'cn=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com', with filter (uniqueMember={0}) in search base ''
2018-03-07 13:59:52.591 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Using filter: (uniqueMember=cn=Test TESTER1,ou=AAA,ou=BBBB,ou=users,dc=dom,dc=company,dc=com)
2018-03-07 13:59:52.614 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-03-07 13:59:52.615 DEBUG 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-03-07 13:59:52.616 ERROR 1384 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        ''
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        ''
 ]; remaining name ''
```

Comment: Can you try with a user that has no special characters in their CN? There might be an issue with that. So, use `CN=someuser,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com`.

Comment: No, its not under my control.  CN is stored 'lastName, Firstname' in this system.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it is trying to read group memberships for your user, but somehow the user's DN is garbled:

```
Found DN: CN=user\, lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com
```

and then the search for memberships is done using:

```
Using filter: (uniqueMember=cn=user\,lname.,OU=AAA,OU=BBBB,OU=users,DC=dom,DC=company,DC=com)
```

It is *stripping the space* from the user's CN, hence Active Directory is telling you `2001 (NO_OBJECT)` - and rightly so. 
Seems like a bug in the LDAP handler somewhere.

**EDIT**

Looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java it would seem that the following code snippet from `searchForMultipleAttributeValues()` is reformatting your user DN:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        encodedParams[i] = LdapEncoder.filterEncode(params[i].toString());
    }

    String formattedFilter = MessageFormat.format(filter, encodedParams);
    logger.debug("Using filter: " + formattedFilter);
```

So it is either the `LdapEncoder.filterEncode()` call or the call to `MessageFormat.format()`. Definitely a bug in Spring LDAP.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at that line, when I anonymized the data that line was a little different, I did it by hand and removed the space by mistake. But I did noticed that it became "uniqueMember=cn=user\5c, lname.,"  Which if I understand you correctly is having the same effect.  I'll update the question.